# Entity Framework save error on removed list items

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting a strange error when trying to save an object with a removed-from list of sub-objects using Entity Framework.

Specifically, I've got a list of objects of type 'a'.  These objects connect with each other via a connection object of type 'b'.  An 'a' object can hold many 'b' objects, and each 'b' object holds only a single 'a' object.  So basically, I have a network of 'a' objects with 0 or more connections to other 'a' objects via 'b' objects.

A given 'a' object's list of 'b' objects is variable; 'b' objects can be added or removed from an 'a' object's list.  However, when a 'b' object is removed from an 'a' object's list, this sometimes causes Entity Framework to error out when trying to save the network of 'a' objects later on down the line.  An 'a' object's 'b' object removal code looks like this:

```
public void RemoveConnection(b connectionObject)
    {
        myBObjects.remove(connectionObject);
    }
```

This method works fine when the code is running, and the 'a' objects have a correct list of 'b' objects at save time.  The following is the save code:

```
using (var db = new PersistenceContext())
            {
                db.NetworkOfAs.Add(network);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

If a 'b' object has never been removed from an 'a' object's list of 'b' objects, the above works just fine.  If a 'b' object is removed from an 'a' object's list of 'b' objects but the list of 'b' objects remains greater or equal to length 1, the above also works fine.  However, if a 'b' object was added and then removed from an 'a' object's list of 'b' objects such that the 'a' object's list of 'b' objects returns to length 0, I get the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_dbo.BObjects_dbo.AObjects_Id". The conflict occurred in database 
"NetworkDatabase.PersistenceContext\", table \"dbo.AObjects\", column 'Id'
```

I've been digging into debugging this for several days now, and it seems pretty apparent that this is being caused by Entity Framework trying to save the 'b' objects which have been removed from a given 'a' object's list of 'b' objects.  However, I have no idea how to prevent this, and can't seem to find anything describing this particular issue.

Any help is much appreciated, and if this explanation is missing any necessary details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

By the exception you exposed, I would say that there are B objects that were saved in Db, and then you just remove the reference they have to A object, and not actually remove the object it self. So, without a reference, it conflicts with the foreign key for B objects.